# Issue with Axios interceptors

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have issue with axios.  I get new access token but it sends not updated access token with further request and I get same unauthenticated error.

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.defaults.baseURL='http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'
axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type']='application/json'

let refresh = false

axios.interceptors.response.use(res =>res ,async error =>{
    if (error.response.status === 401 && !refresh ){
        refresh=true
        const response= await axios.post('/user/refresh/',{},{withCredentials:true})
        
        if(response.status===200){
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']='JWT '+response.data.token
            return axios(error.config)
        }
        

        }
        
    refresh=false
    return error
})
```

[image]

Same access token with both requests is sent. After refresh request it doesn't change authorization header. It only changes when I refresh page

Comment: Have you tried `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;`?

Comment: Yes. Same issue

Comment: Are you sure `Authorization` header is not defined in requests and there is no error logged in console? BTW, you probably need to return `return Promise.reject(error);` instead of `error` in the interceptor.

Comment: Could you log `error.config` to see if the header is set to the updated token?

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh it sends expired (same) token as with first request. When I refresh page manualy i get data and I see request is sent with updated token

Comment: @c0m1t Authorization is defined only in this file

Comment: So it is probably because you do not update the refresh token. When you send an expired token, do you get 401? If so, you only set `refresh` to false and do not send a request to `/user/refresh` endpoint to get the new token. Please try to debug your code or add logs to see what happens in each line.

Comment: @c0m1t  /user/refresh request returns new access token but it not applies in  Authorization header  with second request. I see same expired token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `axios` initiate a request, it takes all the configuration **at that moment**. So, when you update the default config with the new token, it does **not** modify the configuration of the request that has been sent **before**. Hence, `error.config` contains the old token. You need to modify it directly.

We can modify this block:

```
if(response.status===200){
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']='JWT '+response.data.token
            return axios(error.config)
        }
```

to:

```
if(response.status===200){
    // we update the new token here but it does not affect the config of the previous request. 
    // error.config is not updated.
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']='JWT '+response.data.token
    
    // now we resend the request that produces the error
    // we need to update the config directly
    error.config.headers['Authorization'] = 'JWT '+response.data.token
    return axios(error.config)
}
```

Comment: thanks. It works now. Also had to add "refresh = false"  because sometimes  didn't send refresh request. Now will look forward how to handle multiple requests